# unable to convert JSON object to global array

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, express

I am using express Js.
After getting data from MongoDB Atlas trying to send this data to my index.ejs page, for this I have converted my object to an array and make it globally, But I am totally failed to get this array or JSON object.

```
app.get("/", function (request, response) {

    model.find({},function (err, data1) {
        if (err) {
            response.send({
                statusCode: 500,
                message: 'Data did not selected'
            })
        } else {              
            let wholeArray = Object.keys(data1).map(key => data1[key]);
            app.locals.wholeArray = wholeArray;
        };
    });
    response.render("index");

});
```

I have tried this way to access this on my index page but it also failed.

```
var wholeArray = data1;
app.locals.wholeArray= wholeArray;
```

here is my index.ejs page code for accessing the JSON object.

```
<% if(wholeArray.length) { %>
    <% wholeArray.forEach(function(entry)  { %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="muted pull-right"><%= entry.today %></div>
            <%= entry.title %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <%= entry.content %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% }) %>
<% }else { %>
    <span style="font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600;">No entries! </span><a href="/newEntry" class="btn btn-primary">Add Entry</a>
<% } %>
```

Comment: IIRC the second argument to `ServerResponse#render` function is an object that passes data to the template, like `response.render('index', { wholeArray })`. Not sure if manipulating globals is a good idea in general.

Comment: Bro changes give me an error, wholeArray is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `responde.render("index");` outside of the callback function from `mongo.find`, which means you are not waiting for the data to be retrieved to render the "index.ejs" file.

You need to call `response.render("index");` inside of the callback function from `mongo.find`, like this:

```
app.get("/", function (request, response) {

    model.find({},function (err, data1) {
        if (err) {
            response.send({
                statusCode: 500,
                message: 'Data did not selected'
            })
        } else {              
            let wholeArray = Object.keys(data1).map(key => data1[key]);
            app.locals.wholeArray = wholeArray;
            response.render("index");
        };
    });
});
```

Note that you can pass locals temporary locals to [res.render](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) as its second argument, like this: `res.render("index", wholeArray);`

Also, why do you need to create an array? You can send the object returned from mongo directly, which will probably be easier to manipulate in the template engine.